# What is the minimum amount of information required to compute the number of edges in a subgraph of an arbitrary simple graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to compute the distribution of edge counts created by taking a set of $k$ nodes at random from a given graph of $n$ nodes. I think it would simplify my analysis if I could reduce the problem from considering the entire adjacency matrix to a simpler data summary.

More formally, for a simple graph $G = (V, E)$ (undirected, no self loops) with size $n = |V|$, let $H$ be a subgraph of $G$ induced by a list of $k \le n$ vertices. What information must I know about $G$ in order to know the number of edges in $H$?

Another way of saying this is that a data structure for $G$ has size $O(n^2)$. Is there any data structure that can be produced from $G$ that has smaller order and would allow me to compute the number of edges in an arbitrary subgraph on $k$ vertices? $k$ is known in advance (though not the exact list of nodes), so this can be part of the data structure.

To give an example of a non-solution, the list of degrees of each vertex is not sufficient. Consider the degree distribution $(1, 1, 1, 1)$. If the first two nodes are selected, it could either be the case that there is an edge between them (the subgraph has one edge) or that each has an edge to a vertex in the complement set (the subgraph has zero edges).